ValueError: Expected input batch_size (8) to match target batch_size (2048)
I am new to this field.
I have been stuck on this for quite a while now, and everything I tried has not helped me.
I want to finetune a model with data I have for machine translation. I am using the torch and transformers libraries.
Here is my code:
tokenizer = MT5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small")
model = MT5ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small")
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./data",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir="./logs",
)


trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_ds,
    eval_dataset=evalu_ds,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)

train_dataset and eval_dataset are of type CustomDataset class I have defined that inherits from torch.utils.data.Dataset. They return:
return {
    "input_ids": input_ids_lang1,
    "attention_mask": attention_mask_lang1,
    "labels": input_ids_lang2,
    #"attention_mask_lang2": attention_mask_lang2.float()
}

tokenizer is MT5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mt5-small")
I get this error:
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3060, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (8) to match target batch_size (2048).

printing out the shapes of input and target Tensors in the functional.py I get
input:  torch.Size([8, 256])
target: torch.Size([2048])
Just as it is mentioned here the target size seems to be 8 * 256 = 2048. But trying the CustomTrainer class did not help either.
I think the main problem I have is understanding what that means.
I tried many different variants, different models.
I expect to not get this error
